# Inheritance in yml rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have a yml file which is something like this I have written all the roles in
roles tag.

admin tag inherits all attributes from roles but i want defalut tag should inherit only role_5 . how to do it??

```
 roles: &all
 role_1: "edit"
 role_2: "create"
 role_3: "read"
 role_4: "update"
 role_5: "writepost"

 admin: 
 <<: *all #inherits all 


 default : 
  <<:only inherit role_5 # what should i write ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
roles: &all
 role_1: "edit"
 role_2: "create"
 role_3: "read"
 role_4: "update"
 role_5: &role_5
   "writepost"

 admin: 
 <<: *all #inherits all 


 default: *role_5
```